# Dropout not reducing loss in pytorch but works fine with keras

Tags: python, keras, pytorch

I was comparing loss for two simple MLP models with and without dropout on both TF/Keras and Pytorch frameworks (on Keras imdb dataset). But with PyTorch I am not getting the same results as I hoped for and was wondering perhaps what I am doing incorrectly.

```
# Keras - IMDB Dataset
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(16, activation = "relu", input_shape= (10000,)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5)) # comment out this line for no dropout model
model.add(Dense(16, activation = "relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.5)) # comment out this line for no dropout model
model.add(Dense(1, activation = "sigmoid"))

model.compile(
    optimizer = "rmsprop",
    loss = "binary_crossentropy",
    metrics = ["accuracy"]
)

history = model.fit(
    X_train,
    y_train, 
    epochs = 20,
    batch_size =  512,
    validation_data = (X_val, y_val)
)
```

The results I obtained in keras (Left figure without dropout and right with dropout)

[image]

```
# Pytorch - same IMDB dataset from keras

class MLP(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_dims, l1, l2, out_dims):
        super(MLP, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(in_dims, l1)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(l1, l2)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(l2, out_dims)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=0.5)

    def forward(self, X):
        out = F.relu(self.fc1(X))
        out = self.dropout(out) # comment out this line for no dropout model
        out = F.relu(self.fc2(out))
        out = self.dropout(out) # comment out this line for no dropout model
        out = F.sigmoid(self.fc3(out))
        return out

model = MLP(10000, 16, 16, 1)
optimizer = optim.RMSprop(model.parameters(), lr = 0.001)
criterion = nn.BCELoss()

min_val_loss = np.inf
losses = []
val_losses = []
accuracy = []
val_accuracy = []

for e in range(0,20):
    running_loss = 0
    for i,(X_train, y_train) in enumerate(train_loader):
        yhat = model.forward(X_train)
        loss = criterion(yhat.flatten(), y_train)
        running_loss += loss.item()

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

    losses.append(running_loss / (i+1)) #note its i+1 since i starts from 0

    model.eval()
    with torch.no_grad():
        running_val_loss = 0
        for i,(X_val, y_val) in enumerate(val_loader):
            yhat_val = model.forward(X_val)
            val_loss = criterion(yhat_val.flatten(), y_val)
            running_val_loss += val_loss.item()

        val_losses.append(running_val_loss / (i + 1))

        if val_loss < min_val_loss:
            best_params = model.state_dict()
            min_val_loss = val_loss 
    
    print(f"epochs : {e}, train_loss : {loss}, val_loss : {val_loss}")
```

Figure on the left is the result from no dropout model which has similar results to the keras model. However the one with dropout doesnot have the same behaviour.

[image]

Comment: have you tried setting the seed to be the same for both, for example, using [lightning's `seed_everything`](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pytorch_lightning.utilities.seed.html#pytorch_lightning.utilities.seed.seed_everything)

Comment: Nahh i havent, but i tried a couple of times and ended up with similar results for both everytime.

Comment: Does it improve if you declare and use two separate drouput layers?